# Why is liquid so inactive and (according to statistics) not being used yet?

Tags: scalability, sidechains, liquid

After years of development 3 Months ago Liquid (the side chain project) was announced. If you look at https://liquid.horse/ you can find the following statistics as of right now:

> Sidechain Stats Genesis Block September 27, 2018 Sidechain
>
> Transactions  3458
>
> Sidechain Blocks  125344 / 223.9 MB
>
> Expected / Missing Blocks 144622 / 19278 (15.38%)
>
> Entry (peg-in) Transactions   96
>
> Exit (peg-out) Transactions   30
>
> Liquid Federation Wallet  25.26 BTC / $97,905 USD

125k blocks of which 97% are empty but with a memory footprint of 223 MB of data to store 3458 transactions within the sidechain seems pointless at this time.

When liquid was announced several exchanges and services announced to run a liquid Server.

- Is it just taking time for those players to integrate liquid properly?
- When will this take off?